# Echarts Custom Legend based on graph data range

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a simple bar graph that I would want the legend to show specific range value with its corresponding color. In the example below, I'd like to have two legends:

1. blue color with text '0-70%'
2. redcolor with text '71-100%'

This is to inform the user on what the bar color represents.

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

option = {
  legend: {
    type: 'plain',
    formatter: function(name) {
      return '0 - 70%';
    },
    data: [{
      name: 'days',
      icon: 'rect'
    }],
    show: true
  },
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: [{
    data: ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU'],
    gridIndex: 0
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    gridIndex: 0,
    max: 100,
    splitNumber: 2
  }],
  grid: [{
    height: 200,
    width: 400
  }],
  series: [
    // These series are in the first grid.
    {
      name: 'days',
      type: 'bar',
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      data: [{
          value: 90,
          itemStyle: {
            color: getColor(80)
          }
        },
        22,
        56,
        76
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function getColor(value) {
  if (value > 70) return 'rgba(179, 26, 26, 1)';
  else return 'rgba(26, 179, 179, 1)';
}

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<html>
      <header><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.1/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-OTbGFYPLe3jhy4bUwbB8nls0TFgz10kn0TLkmyA+l3FyivDs31zsXCjOis7YGDtE2Jsy0+fzW+3/OVoPVujPmQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div id="main" style="width: 100%; height: 400px">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```